# Error while giving Powershell access to Target System from Source machine

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I am basically a C# guy but my requirement is to give Powershell access to the remote/target systems (Say Client) from my system (Say Server). I am part of the administrator group in those remote/target machines. Also, all the systems including mine are in the same domain. I tried running these commands in my system (Server)-

> Enable-PSRemoting -Force
>
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName client01,client02 -ScriptBlock { SET -executionPolicy ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted }

I get following error message-
[Powershell Remoting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpXcG.png)

Comment: Is this really related to C#?

Comment: You're trying to remotely enable remoting, don't you? Sounds for me like you run in the chicken or egg dilemma!  ;-)

Comment: @Hexfire, Sorry, I removed the C# tag and replaced it with more relevant tag - Windows-Scripting along with Powershell tag. Thanks

Comment: @Olaf, well kind of yes :P I am actually writing a UpgradeWizard tool in C# where in I need to give access to the powershell and run commands in client systems using the UpgradeWizard in my Server machine.

Comment: @Vidyadhar  That's the problem. To be able to send commands through Powershell remoting to another computer you need to have Powershell remoting already enabled on this computer. That's what I meant with chicken and egg dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `Enable-PSRemoting` on your target systems first or apply some group policy that achieves the same end

If you need something only small scale or are just in testing phase, simply remote desktop to your clients and run `Enable-PSRemoting -force` from an elevated shell.

There are already [pretty](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33634.enable-powershell-remoting-via-group-policy-on-windows7windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) [good](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-powershell-remoting-via-group-policy/) [articles](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbooks.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/content/manuscript/configuring-remoting-via-gpo.html) out there that explain how to use group policy to enable remote powershell on a large number of clients.

Comment: Hey @veefu, thanks for responding. I totally understand this. But I am trying to replicate the things which is achieved by running to Enable-PSremoting Command in remote machine (Like Enabling WinRM firewall exception, Create WinRM listener on HTTP, enable WinRM service etc.). Unfortunately, I am running into the requirement which demands me to achieve this from the source machine.